# After animation and keyboard close the animated image moves

Tags: swift, storyboard, uiviewanimation

I have a problem after animated a logo on the main login screen. The screen looks correct when visibly seeing the screen. Once entering the email address field and typing into the field (or closing the keyboard), the logo will go back to it's original location.

On viewDidAppear, I animate the logo.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    animateScreen()
}


private func animateScreen() {
    mainLogo.fadeIn()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.2, animations: {
        self.mainLogo.frame.origin.y -= 150
    }) { (isCompleted) in
        self.showFields()
    }
}
```

I am using a storyboard with centerX and top constraints on the image initially centered on the login screens.

If there's a better solution, I'll gladly look at alternatives.

[image: This is after the animation and screen loads]
[image: this is during typing into the email address field]
[image: These are the constraints for the fields]

Comment: Can u show how u are giving constraints to ImageView and textfields?

Comment: I think your logoImageView constraint is dependant on email and password textfield

Comment: I added a screenshot of the constraints. Maybe it would be easier for me to programmatically add the UIImageView outside of the storyboard and animate it.